# Famous people API

Tags: api, rest

I'm looking for an API for retrieving data about famous people, and most preferably to retrieve info about inspirational famous women in the last 100 years. Can you please tell me where to start looking? Is there any good REST API that I can use??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more **actual** information about the definitions of *famous*  and (especially) *info*. And does it have to be free?

Comment: I once ran down this rabbit hole trying to see if 2016 was a particularly deadly year for celebrities (it doesn't appear to be), and decided that any person listed in Wikipedia (and thus wikidata) is famous by Wikipedia's inclusion criteria. It's far from perfect, but that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 6):

You will need a way of measuring fame, but wikidata will probably be a good resource for you.

Here are women who could have been alive in the last one hundred years, who have the most Wikimedia articles about them (across all the different language Wikipedias, Wikiquotes, etc), and who have pages about them on English WikiQuote.

http://tinyurl.com/y9vrw835

```
SELECT ?person ?name ?linkcount ?wikipedia_article
WHERE
{
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;   # human
     wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072 ;  # gender: female
     wdt:P569 ?born .
  FILTER (?born >= "1820-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) .
  ?person wikibase:sitelinks ?linkcount .
  FILTER (?linkcount > 50) .
  ?person rdfs:label ?name FILTER(lang(?name)="en").
  ?wikipedia_article schema:about ?person .
  ?wikipedia_article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikiquote.org/> .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?linkcount)
LIMIT 100
```